# Including already existing variable in a function

Tags: php, function

Im trying to make a function, that takes an input, determines its value, and outputs a word from an already existing array that has been included in the script. The problem is the output is blank, i believe the function ignores variables already in the script, is there a way to change this so existing variables arent ignored by the function?

Here is the function:

The words need to be from an array because of multi-lingual requirements.

```
function get_genre($id)
{
    if($id == "1"){
        $genre = $lang['277'];
    }
    if($id == "2"){
        $genre = $lang['278'];
    }
    if($id == "3"){
        $genre = $lang['279'];
    }
    if($id == "4"){
        $genre = $lang['280'];
    }
    if($id == "5"){
        $genre = $lang['281'];
    }
    if($id == "6"){
        $genre = $lang['282'];
    }
    if($id == "7"){
        $genre = $lang['283'];
    }
    if($id == "8"){
        $genre = $lang['284'];
    }
    if($id == "9"){
        $genre = $lang['285'];
    }
    if($id == "10"){
        $genre = $lang['286'];
    }
    if($id == "11"){
        $genre = $lang['287'];
    }
    if($id == "12"){
        $genre = $lang['288'];
    }
    if($id == "13"){
        $genre = $lang['289'];
    }
    if($id == "14"){
        $genre = $lang['290'];
    } 
    if($id == "15"){
        $genre = $lang['374'];
    }
    return $genre;
}
```

Comment: You could change the entire code above into one line `$index = 276 + (int)$id; $genre = $lang["$index"];`

Comment: @xbonez, well if `$id` was 15, that wouldnt work, however i see your point

Comment: use a `switch` statement, to help tidy your code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_genre($id)
{
    global $lang;
    ....
}
```

or

```
function get_genre($id, $lang) //Must pass $lang array to function here
{

}
```

Comment: i don't understand, in your example `$genre = $lang['277'];`, $lang already has a value because it has already been defined previously. If you set it as global within the function, it doesn't allow you to use its values set previously, from outside. Besides, using global is a very bad habit. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1557787/1291428

Comment: @Sebas While I agree that `global` isn't the best system in existence, if the variable is contained within the same file as the function, and always will be, there's no problem with it, in this case. Also, as far as my knowledge and experience leads, `global` reads the variable in it's current state, and after the function call, it is read as it is. It's not passed as a copy, but rather a reference, so it should work fine.

Comment: It sounds like a trick to me, an ugly one. If you really want to use global, at least use it on the top of the stack...

Comment: @Sebas: Hey, if it works, it works. No one said it had to be pretty.

Comment: @Sebas so after trolling everyone on this page about being wrong, you delete your answer after i pointed out it didnt work and there was multiple syntax errors? Classy.

Comment: @JimmyBanks, if this helped you out, could you upvote it? Every point helps :)

Comment: Yay :) Someone must have been annoyed and downvoted me then.. odd. Oh well :)

Comment: The currently given answers are perfectly inestetic and against what i consider healthy programming, that's why I downvoted them. Regarded my answer, I just tried it on my computer and it works. The way you answered made me realize that afterall, to me it was not worth loosing any additional time, that's why a aborted my attempt to help. Good luck

Comment: I have to add that I didn't troll, just tried to make the readers understand that the provided answers were not of my taste. Please bring any moderation if you think it went out of bounds. I apologize if it did.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_genre($id)
{
 global $lang;

if($id == "1"){
    $genre = $lang['277'];
}
if($id == "2"){
    $genre = $lang['278'];
}
if($id == "3"){
    $genre = $lang['279'];
}
if($id == "4"){
    $genre = $lang['280'];
}
if($id == "5"){
    $genre = $lang['281'];
}
if($id == "6"){
    $genre = $lang['282'];
}
if($id == "7"){
    $genre = $lang['283'];
}
if($id == "8"){
    $genre = $lang['284'];
}
if($id == "9"){
    $genre = $lang['285'];
}
if($id == "10"){
    $genre = $lang['286'];
}
if($id == "11"){
    $genre = $lang['287'];
}
if($id == "12"){
    $genre = $lang['288'];
}
if($id == "13"){
    $genre = $lang['289'];
}
if($id == "14"){
    $genre = $lang['290'];
} 
if($id == "15"){
    $genre = $lang['374'];
}
return $genre;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

While this isn't ideal, have you considered using an associative array?

```
var $lookupArray = array();
$lookupArray["1"] = $lang['274'];
....
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
function get_genre($id)
{            

   return(array_key_exists($id,$lookupArray)) ? $lookupArray[$id] : null;                      

}
```

Comment: there won't be any access to $lookupArray within get_genre